# Invalid JSON data PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, knockout.js, yii2

I generated a Json from knockout.js and created something like this:

```
{"po":"11446019431405","orders":[{"product":{"ID":"2","product_name":"A","product_code":""},"ID":"2","product_name":"A","product_code":"","price":"11","qty":1,"discount":0,"subtotal":11,"amount":11},{"product":{"ID":"1","product_name":"B","product_code":""},"ID":"1","product_name":"B","product_code":"","price":"10","qty":1,"discount":0,"subtotal":"10","amount":10}],"grandTotal":21}
```

I tried both json_decode and Json::decode from Yii, but it didn't work. What went wrong? Is there a special way to parse this in PHP?

Below is my code for reference.

My Javascript Code:

```
$.post(url, ko.toJSON(orderCollection), {}, "json");
```

On my php code I tried both $_POST and Yii::$app->request->post() and both failed

```
public function actionPostorders() {
        $request = Yii::$app->request->post();
        echo Json::decode($request);
    }
```

My error when using Json::decode is:

```
PHP Warning 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given' 

in C:\xampp\yii2\controllers\PurchaseController.php:121
```

A similar error goes when using vanilla PHP

```
json_decode($_POST)

PHP Warning 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given' 

in C:\xampp\yii2\controllers\PurchaseController.php:121
```

This is what I get when I vardump my $_POST

```
array(1) { ["{"po":"11446021195934","orders":"]=> array(1) { ["{"product":{"ID":"2","product_name":"A","product_code":""},"ID":"2","product_name":"A","product_code":"","price":"11","qty":1,"discount":0,"subtotal":11,"amount":11},{"product":{"ID":"1","product_name":"B","product_code":""},"ID":"1","product_name":"B","product_code":"","price":"10","qty":1,"discount":0,"subtotal":"10","amount":10}"]=> string(0) "" } }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error or blank output?

Comment: @Samir I'm getting an error

Comment: Please post the error.

Comment: json decode needs parameter to be a string. You cannot decode POST variables since $_POST is an array.

Comment: @Samir posted the error

Comment: You are decoding POST variables rather decoding json encoded output from knockout.js. You cannot decode POST values as $_POST is an array and json_decode expects parameter to be a string.

Comment: @Samir hmmm...in that case, I must not insert it to POST. where should I put it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93573/discussion-between-samir-and-corbee).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that `$_POST` is an array, you actually want to do

```
json_decode($_POST[0]);
```

In order to decode only the first object in your post array.

However, you'll quickly notice that this won't work either; the `$_POST` array expects you to pass in a key-value json object, or an array. In your case, you do pass through a json object, but it becomes weirdly formatted because you do not pass through a key. I'm not entirely certain about this, but by the looks of your `var_dump`ed array, I'm quite certain the issue is that you do not pass it in an array. I also would like to point out that if you set the correct headers and just pass the object, the backend should be able to read it, just as easily as it reads `form-data`

Comment: I get PHP Notice 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Undefined offset: 0', I think this is close, the question is, how do you call $_POST if it doesn't have a array key or index name

Comment: It looks like your array key is weirdly `"{"po":"11446021195934","orders":"`. Also, it shouldn't be `0` I realised, you'll want to be using the key of the array you sent. Make sure that you, from your front end send something like `{"data":yourJsonObject}`, and then access `$_POST['data']`. Sorry about the offset issue, completely forgot that for a sec. Alternatively, you could just wrap your entire object in an array in your frontend. So if you'd pass `[yourJsonObject]` to the backend, you could use `$_POST[0]`.

Comment: added a key so $_POST['json'] works, unfortunately I get Array to string conversion error

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST['json'])` give you?

Comment: string(512) "{"po":"11446023470585","orders":[{"product":{"ID":"2","product_name":"Insulated Terminal Lugs 1.25 - 3R","product_code":""},"ID":"2","product_name":"Insulated Terminal Lugs 1.25 - 3R","product_code":"","price":"14","qty":1,"discount":0,"subtotal":14,"amount":14},{"product":{"ID":"1","product_name":"Insulated Terminal Lugs 1.25 - 3Y","product_code":""},"ID":"1","product_name":"Insulated Terminal Lugs 1.25 - 3Y","product_code":"","price":"10","qty":1,"discount":0,"subtotal":"10","amount":10}],"grandTotal":24}"

Comment: How could you end up getting array to string conversion? To me it seems you do something like `echo json_decode($_POST['json'])` or another string function rather than `var_dump(json_decode($_POST['json']))` for that to happen. I believe you're now decoding correctly, and the issue is rather you attempting to directly output the array :)

Comment: you're right, it works when using var_dump. Why is that?

Comment: @Corbee as said, you have correctly decided the array now. You can hence not access it as a string, because you just converted it from a JSON string to an array. Rather, you can now access the entries with something like `$decoded['po']`, where `$decoded` is your newly decoded array. Conclusion: you're already done decoding, so now you can use the data as you like!

Comment: I'm confused. $decoded['orders'] gives me the whole var_dump.

Comment: @Corbee it should only be returning an array of all your orders, and not the PO number. Remember that you only have two keys in your array; `po` and `orders`, so `$decoded['orders']` returns nearly all content.

Comment: unfortunately, it's still giving me the whole var_dump whether I use orders or po

Comment: @Corbee hmm, strange. What does `var_dump($decoded)` look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is correct according to JSLint

```
{
    "po":"11446019431405",
    "orders":
    [
        {
            "product":
            {
                "ID":"2","product_name":"A",
                "product_code":""
            },
            "ID":"2",
            "product_name":"A",
            "product_code":"",
            "price":"11","qty":1,
            "discount":0,
            "subtotal":11,
            "amount":11
        },
        {
            "product":
            {
                "ID":"1","product_name":"B",
                "product_code":""
            },
            "ID":"1",
            "product_name":"B",
            "product_code":"",
            "price":"10",
            "qty":1,
            "discount":0,
            "subtotal":"10",
            "amount":10
        }
    ],
        "grandTotal":21
}
```

Compressed:

```
{"po":"11446019431405","orders":[{"product":{"ID":"2","product_name":"A","product_code":""},"ID":"2","product_name":"A","product_code":"","price":"11","qty":1,"discount":0,"subtotal":11,"amount":11},{"product":{"ID":"1","product_name":"B","product_code":""},"ID":"1","product_name":"B","product_code":"","price":"10","qty":1,"discount":0,"subtotal":"10","amount":10}],"grandTotal":21}
```

And run this compressed one with JSLint, nothing went wrong. So it might go wrong with your handling of the JSON.

Comment: @L Ja You're right, my problem now is figuring why $_POST isn't working

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what Json::decode is doing, but with standard php it should return an object, so you cannot echo an object or an array, try to print_r or var_dump the variable like this.

```
$json = '{"po":"11446019431405","orders":[{"product":{"ID":"2","product_name":"A","product_code":""},"ID":"2","product_name":"A","product_code":"","price":"11","qty":1,"discount":0,"subtotal":11,"amount":11},{"product":{"ID":"1","product_name":"B","product_code":""},"ID":"1","product_name":"B","product_code":"","price":"10","qty":1,"discount":0,"subtotal":"10","amount":10}],"grandTotal":21}';

print_r( json_decode($json));
```

result

```
stdClass Object
(
    [po] => 11446019431405
    [orders] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [ID] => 2
                            [product_name] => A
                            [product_code] => 
                        )

                    [ID] => 2
                    [product_name] => A
                    [product_code] => 
                    [price] => 11
                    [qty] => 1
                    [discount] => 0
                    [subtotal] => 11
                    [amount] => 11
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [product] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [ID] => 1
                            [product_name] => B
                            [product_code] => 
                        )

                    [ID] => 1
                    [product_name] => B
                    [product_code] => 
                    [price] => 10
                    [qty] => 1
                    [discount] => 0
                    [subtotal] => 10
                    [amount] => 10
                )

        )

    [grandTotal] => 21
)
```

Comment: I'm encountering error in json_decode($_POST) I don't know why

Comment: @Corbee because you have to decode only the variable you need not all the $_POST, eg: json_decode($_POST['my_variable'])

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code ?

```
 $request = Yii::$app->request->post();
 $jsondecode = CJSON::decode($request, true);
 print_r($jsondecode);
```

Comment: Exception 'yii\base\InvalidParamException' with message 'Invalid JSON data.' 

in C:\xampp\yii2\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\helpers\BaseJson.php:71

Comment: It doesn't make it out of Json::decode, I still get Invalid JSON data

Comment: Can you change   $request = Yii::$app->request->post();    to     $request  = file_get_contents('php://input');